# Sharepoint 2013 picture library slideshow

Tags: picture-library, slidelibrary

I Want to use picture library slideshow web part in my share point 2013 portal
but the size of pictures are too small how can I fix size of my pictures in web part?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately it is not supported to configure in web part what image type (original, web or thumbnail) should be displayed in `Picture Library Slideshow  Web Part`, but you could try to customize the rendering of slideshow using the following approach.

The solution described below allows to display original (full-sized) images  in Slideshow web part.

Step 1. Insert the `Script Editor` web part on the page where  `Picture Library Slideshow` web part resides.

Step 2. Inset the following JavaScript code into `Script Editor` web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function SlideshowObjectInitializer() {

  ShowPic = (function(ShowPicOrig) {
      return function() {

           var ssObj = arguments[0];  //SlideShow object
           var curPicIdx=ssObj.index; //current picture index

           ShowPicOrig.apply(this, arguments); //call original ShowPic

           //apply some changes to display original picture in SlideShow control
           ssObj.image.src = ssObj.linkArray[curPicIdx]; //display original image instead of web image
           //change picture & container size to auto instead of fixed (by default web image size is used)
             ssObj.image.setAttribute('height','100%'); 
             ssObj.image.setAttribute('width','100%'); 
             var cell = ssObj.cell; 
             cell.style.width = 'auto';
             cell.style.height = 'auto';
             cell.style.display = '';
             var pcell = ssObj.cell.parentNode; 
           pcell.style.width = 'auto';
             pcell.style.height = 'auto';
      };
  })(ShowPic);

}  


ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SlideshowObjectInitializer, 'imglib.js');
</script>
```

The specified code customizes SlideShow control to display original (full-sized) images from Picture library.

> It has been tested in SharePoint 2010/2013.

For more details about customizing Slideshow web part please follow [this blog post](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/beyond-the-slideshow-web-part-capabilities-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Hi dear Vadim and thank you; I tried this script in script editor above of my slideshow web part but it didn't work what was my mistake do you think?

Comment: Hmm, could you please try to place Script Editor wp in the same zone and below Picture Library Slideshow wp

Comment: Hi dear Vadim and thank you, it works for me i SharePoint 2013.......